# Datepicker with React on Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, datepicker, semantic-ui

My application uses the Form.Input from [Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/) library to insert dates. It shows a date-picker on both Chrome and Firefox but not on Safari. I've tried to use the react-datepicker library, but it has different styling and it's difficult to align its inputs with the others from Semantic UI React's Forms. What can I do?

This is an example of Form.Input type that does not work on Safari.

```
<Form.Input
    label='From'
    type='date'
    min={this.state.filters.data_inizio}
    value={moment(this.state.filters.data_fine).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
    onChange={
        (e) => this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            filters: {
                ...this.state.filters,
                data_fine: moment(e.target.value).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            }
        }, this.filter)
    } />
```

Comment: Can you link to Semantic ui React's Date picker? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: It's a simple `Form.Input` with the attribute `type="date"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bad news.

Semantic UI React does not support the input date type.

What are you seeing in Chrome & Firefox is the default browser versions of input with type="date".

Input with type="date" is not supported in Safari.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Browser_compatibility

I tried Semantic UI React and plain side-by-side

```
  <Container>
    <Form>
      <Form.Input
      label='From'
      type='date' 
      min={data_inizio}
      value={moment(data_fine).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
      onChange={
          (e) => this.setState({
            filters: {
                ...filters,
                data_fine: moment(e.target.value).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            }
      }, this.filter)
    } />
    </Form>
    <span><strong>Plain version</strong></span><br/>
    <input type="date" />
  </Container>
```

Full example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GBdoQW

First picker is same as the plain one below. The first only gets some Semantic CSS.

Try in Safari. They are just regular text inputs. :(

Answer (score 9):

You can try this cool date picker called 'react-dates' made by airbnb...

Github: [airbnb / react-dates](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates)  (for documentation)

Official Live Demo : [click here](http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?selectedKind=DateRangePicker%20%28DRP%29&selectedStory=default&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel)

Code sandbox demo (made by me to help you get started) : https://codesandbox.io/s/l5oo5r4pxl

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a new project that implements a universal DatePicker with the style of semantic-ui-react.

[Link to the GitHub repository](https://github.com/arfedulov/semantic-ui-calendar-react)

Answer (score 0):

I found react-dates pretty useless since I'm using yarn not npm and they only added install docs for npm users.

I recommend react-day-picker, good docs, relatively easy to set up.

https://react-day-picker.js.org/

Really stupid that the safari browser devs haven't added a default html datepicker, what a joke of a browser...