# How to make sure input:date is valid?

Tags: html, reactjs, date, input

I am using `<input type="date">` and developed my app in Firefox. Theres is no way on manipulating the date field and the format is alway valid. From https://caniuse.com/input-datetime I see, this is not supported for any browser, e.g. Safari doesn't have a build-in Datepicker for Desktop Browser.

My Format (out-of-the-box) is DD.MM.YYYY and the value is stored as YYYY.MM.DD.
My app is used in Germany only, so the date format for the user to enter is always DD.MM.YYYY.

Safari uses the value format YYYY.MM.DD out of the box. How can I make sure, the date format is always DD.MM.YYYY during entering for the enduser.

This is my input:

```
<input
  id="birthday"
  type="date"
  name="birthday"
  placeholder="Geburtsdatum"
  style={errors.birthday ? { border: "2px solid red" } : {}}
  onChange={(e) => {
    e.target.value = moment(e.target.value).format(
      "YYYY-MM-DD"
    );
    handleChange(e);
  }}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
  value={moment(values.birthday || user.birthday).format(
    "YYYY-MM-DD"
  )}
/>
```

This code looks like this in Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

and like this in Safari:

[image: Safari]

The user is not used to the format YYYY-MM-DD and I want him to enter the format like: DD.MM.YYYY

Comment: See [Datepicker with React on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51650927/11667949)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for my situation. I updated the code

Comment: You can use a `text` input and then use something like [react-input-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask) to enforce the correct format.